# My Mac app is crashing on OS X 10.7 (from tester reports). How can I test on 10.7 when my dev machines are 10.8?

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, osx-mountain-lion

I have a Mac app that I built on the latest Xcode on an OS X 10.8 machine. Some of our beta testers are getting crashes on 10.7. Here in the office we don't have any machines with 10.7 on them.

On iOS we have the simulator to test on iOS 5. How can I do this with the Mac? Do I need to purchase a machine with OS X 10.7 on it in order to test?

Thanks.

Comment: Run OSX Lion in VirtualBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the latest version of VMWare Fusion does OS X virtualization. I'll give that a try.